# Determine numerical infinity for Schrodinger equation $−\psi''(z) − (iz)^ N \psi(z) = E\psi(z)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, asymptotics, runge-kutta-methods

Consider the following one dimensional Schrodinger equation within the complex plane of $z$
$$
−ψ''(z) − (iz)^ N ψ(z) = Eψ(z).
$$
where $N$ can be any **real** number, the boundary condition is $ψ(z) → 0$ as $|z| → ∞$  .

For simplicity, let's replace $z$ to be $x$ and $x$ is real. I set $N=2$, so that I have a harmonic oscillator:
$$
−ψ''(x) + x^ 2 ψ(x) = Eψ(x).
$$
I solve the last equation by using shooting method and implicit runge-kutta integrator. For eigenvalue $E=1$, the corresponding eigenfunction looks like:
[image]
where I set $x=4$ as $+∞$ and $x=-4$ as $-∞$ . For eigenvalue $E=5$, the corresponding eigenfunction looks like:
[image]
where the eigenfunction roughly still exponentially decays at $x=\pm 4$. However, when eigenvalue $E=17$, the corresponding eigenfunction won't exponentially decays at $x=\pm 4$ as shown on the following Fig.
[image]

In fact, the eigenfunction decays at $x=\pm 6$ .
[image]

**My Question**

The numerical infinity should be large (like $x=6$) for large eigenvalue $E$, and small (like $x=4$) for small eigenvalue. If independent from the eigenvalue, I uniformly set numerical infinity as a very large number, it would waste computational resource. So, is there any formula to determine the exact numerical infinity based on different inputted eigenvalue please? Thank you!

Comment: Please don't [cross post](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/23720/9667)

Comment: My question is interdisciplinary between computational science and mathematics. People in the forum know mathematics may not know much about computational science; People in the forum know computational science may not know much about mathematics. To obtain a complete and insightful answer, posting it in both forums is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It seems OP is essentially asking how to determine which regions the wavefunction $\psi(x)$ is oscillatory (decaying)? In quantum mechanics, these regions are called classically allowed (forbidden) regions, respectively. The turning points are determined by the condition that the total energy $$\tag{1} V(x)~=~E$$ matches the potential energy $$\tag{2}V(x)~:=~x^2.$$ So the turning points can be found as $$\tag{3}|x|~=~\sqrt{E}.$$ If the seed values for $x$ should be in the classically forbidden regions, then one should pick $|x|$ a bit bigger than (3).

Comment: I like your answer! It is simple and useful. So, if $E=1$, then the numerical infinity can be $x=\sqrt(1) +$the tail part of decay; if $E=17$, then the numerical infinity can be $x=\sqrt(17) +$the tail part of decay. Then the question is how to determine the length of the tail part. Probably, by just intuition, I uniformly set the length of the tail equal to 2.